# React JS with Axios

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, axios

I have been looking forward to connecting the frontend(ReactJS) with backend(python) using Flask and axios. How can i post something on the Flask app using axios from React JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```js
axios.post(link_to_your_flask_app_route, {
    firstName: 'yacine',
    lastName: 'mahdid'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

There is plenty of documentation on this: [axios cheatsheet](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Axios.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index)
One thing to keep in mind is that your backend doesn't matter. It can be Flask, Django or whatever, you are simply making a Post to a remote API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..can u plz give an example on how i can create a post on flask?

Comment: I dont want to just post it on console but also post it on the flask server.